# Apply floating point values based on 'coded' integers with loops

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of integers that I want to map floating point values to based on the integer value. The floating point columns represent the integer value to which they should be mapped. For each timestep in the floating point dataframe, there should be a new dataframe created.  The final product I'm hoping for is actually a floating point raster.

The dataframe of integers could be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,4,size=(5,5)))
print(df)
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  3  2  3  0
1  3  3  0  1  3
2  1  1  0  2  3
3  3  0  3  0  3
4  1  1  3  0  1
```

And the floating point values could be:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(25).reshape(5,5),
                   index=pd.date_range(start='2012-1-1',end='2012-6-1',freq='M'))
print(df2)
                   0         1         2         3         4
2012-01-31  0.892510  0.186048  0.960318  0.415110  0.930342
2012-02-29  0.944020  0.497700  0.735165  0.106957  0.640663
2012-03-31  0.135279  0.472433  0.761687  0.565476  0.482689
2012-04-30  0.630033  0.719444  0.078893  0.070138  0.392354
2012-05-31  0.686622  0.823896  0.551767  0.898720  0.569068
```

So far, I've been able to do unelegantly with `mask` by explicitly running through the codes and time steps.

```
# Crop code is the column in df2(float) and value in df(int) 
cropcode = 1
# 2012-01-31
ts = 0
df.mask( df == cropcode, df2[cropcode][ts],inplace=True)

print(df)
          0         1  2         3         4
0  0.186048  3.000000  2  3.000000  0.000000
1  3.000000  3.000000  0  0.186048  3.000000
2  0.186048  0.186048  0  2.000000  3.000000
3  3.000000  0.000000  3  0.000000  3.000000
4  0.186048  0.186048  3  0.000000  0.186048
```

...and so on until all values are replaced. In this example, there would be 5 resulting floating point rasters, one for each month. I can't seem to wrangle a good loop to accomplish this for me.

Comment: Sorry, what is your final expected output?

Comment: In this example, it would be 5 dataframes created by replacing the integer values with the value in the corresponding column of the floating point dataframe. For the first time step the new dataframe would be a 5x5 with all 0s replaced with 0.89251, 1s replaced with 0.186048, and so on. The final product I'm hoping for is actually a floating point raster

Comment: No, please write your output in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one way

```
df2.columns=df.columns.astype(int)
df.replace(df2.T.iloc[:,0].to_dict())
Out[15]: 
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.186048  0.415110  0.960318  0.415110  0.892510
1  0.415110  0.415110  0.892510  0.186048  0.415110
2  0.186048  0.186048  0.892510  0.960318  0.415110
3  0.415110  0.892510  0.415110  0.892510  0.415110
4  0.186048  0.186048  0.415110  0.892510  0.186048
```

With for loop

```
l = []
for i in df2.columns:
    l.append(df.replace(df2.T.iloc[:,i].to_dict()))
```

Comment: Ah, I like the df.replace solution. With your loop solution, I'm getting a list of dataframes that are all the same.